# How to extend the native input element in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I am using the native input elemnt with datalist.
And I want it always select the first item as possible after every typing of filtering list.
[image]

How can I extend it as a custom compnent and edit this selection part?

Here is the html code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="productNo">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="w-150">Product No.</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let el;let i=index;"[formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="productNo" list="products" placeholder="...">
      <datalist id="products">
        <option *ngFor="let el of products;" value={{el.productNo}}> {{el.name}}</option>
      </datalist>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: share code or stackblitz to validate!

Comment: I add the html code for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try the `[selected]="item && i == 0"` so if you have a angular matlistoption it gonna be like this

```
 <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of items, let i = index" [selected]="item && i == 0">
     </mat-list-option>
```